# Laravel 7 error Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed during migration

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have a problem migrating my tables in Laravel 7. I am trying to create a relationship of two tables  using belongsToMany. The product table and image table. I get an error 150 Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed when doing migration. Kindly assist.
In migration files :

```
CreateProductsTable:

Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
             $table->id();
             $table->string('title');
             $table->string('filename');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

CreateImages table

```
Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
             $table->id();
             $table->string('title');
             $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

CreateProductsImagesTable

```
 Schema::create('products_images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('image_id')->constrained('Images');
            $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained('Products');
             $table->timestamps();
```

In the model
Products

```
 protected $fillable = ['title','filename'];
}
public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Product','products_images'); 
}
```

In images model
{

```
     protected $fillable = ['title','image'];

 public function products(){
return $this->belongsToMany('Products','products_images');
}
```

In Products Model

```
 protected $fillable = ['title','filename'];

public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Images','products_images'); 
}
}
```

Comment: Is it that you mean that a product can belong to many images and also an images can belong to many products? That's at least what your code delivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define relationship with table, not classes :

```
$table->foreignId('image_id')->constrained('images');
$table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained('products');
```

If your table name match Laravel's conventions, you may ignore the argument of the `constrained` method. So you can do the same with :

```
$table->foreignId('image_id')->constrained();
$table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained();
```

Comment: Thanks but after changing i get this error  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `angoline`.`products_images` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constra
int is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `products_images` add constraint `products_images_image_id_foreign` forei
gn key (`image_id`) references `images` (`id`))

Comment: Make sure `products` and `images` migration file need to run before `products_images` table